# How to run STS in verbose mode from command line

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin, spring-webflow, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

How to run SpringSource Toolsite in verbose mode from command line in Windows ? 
I tried following command:

STS.exe -verbose - consoleLog

But not getting any logs in command prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-verbose` is not an eclipse option.  `-consoleLog` should be printing everything that goes to the error log view to sysout.  If you are not seeing this, then you could edit your STS.ini file and place the option there.

Here is more information on command line arguments:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html

What information are you looking to get? You may be interested in the `-debug [options file]` option.